# Let $(G, \circ )$ be a group where $a\circ a =e, \ \forall a\in G $. Show that $(G, \circ )$ is abelian.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I have a question I'm trying to answer. The question is

> Let $(G, \circ )$ be a group where $a\circ a =e, \ \forall a\in G $. Show that $(G, \circ )$ is abelian. [Here $e$ is the identity element.]

How would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $x=a\circ b$ where $a,b\in G$ are arbitrary.

Clearly $(a\circ b)\circ( b \circ a)= e$, so $x^{-1}=b\circ a$. Then $a\circ b=x=x^{-1}=b\circ a$.